# Spark HDFS read fails when using Mesos

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

We have set up a small Spark cluster, and we were testing if it could read from HDFS. We are testing with a small job which just reads from HDFS and writes the amount of lines in the read file to stdout.
This works fine when running with a local master (`local[*]`).
However, when are trying to submit the job to Mesos (`mesos://zk://host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181/mesos`), we get the following error:

```
16/03/14 11:10:27 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, XXX): java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams; Host Details : local host is: "XXXX"; destination host is: "XXX":9000;
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1553)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityInfo: Provider org.apache.hadoop.security.AnnotatedSecurityInfo not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:365)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getTokenInfo(SecurityUtil.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerToken(SaslRpcClient.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:717)
    ... 41 more
```

All Spark nodes have the same version of the Hadoop library (2.6.0), and the same configuration. I've checked manually if the class exists, and also by testing with `Class.forName(...)` in the Spark Shell.
We are using Kerberos for authentication, and all nodes have a valid Kerberos ticket for reading.

We are running Spark 1.5.1.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: the most similar issue found http://hadoop-common.472056.n3.nabble.com/Issue-with-Hadoop-Kerberos-security-as-client-td4049468.html ... maybe it's helping you somehow

Comment: I've seen that, but we are not using JNI. Just the regular Spark and Hadoop jars.

Comment: Have you configured hadoop home in mesos configuration? If you don't then you can do it by writing HADOOP_HOME in file /etc/mesos-slave/hadoop_home.

Comment: @avr it was missing and I added it (set to `/etc/hadoop/conf`), but it didn't fix the error

Comment: You have to add it to /etc/mesos-slave/hadoop_home and not to hadoop Conf.

Comment: The release notes for Spark 1.6 mention a few fixes about YARN and Kerberos, maybe an upgrade could help... Anyway, did you try to tinker with `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and/or `spark.executor.extraClassPath` to force `hadoop-common.jar` in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter `spark.driver.extraClassPath` would only change it on the driver node, which works fine. The exception comes from a slave node.

Comment: Also I didn't find any mention of YARN or Kerberos in the 1.6 release notes

Comment: Oops, you're right, SPARK-11821 and SPARK-11265 are about Hive specifically, not HDFS. And the other JIRAs I was thinking about are about CLASSPATH precedence, they have no impact here.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter No change in the error after adding Hadoop home to the executor classpath.

Comment: @arv fixed the hadoop_home, didn't change the output.