# Spark on Mesos reading from a secured HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mesos

We have deployed Spark on Mesos and we are having problems when we are trying to read from HDFS.
Out of the box we tried using Kerberos, which works fine in local mode, but fails when running on Mesos (even though we made sure that each machine had a valid token).

My question is, what alternatives do we have?

According to [this document](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html) the only two options are Kerberos and shared secret, from which Kerberos only works on YARN.
I've not found any article how a shared secret could be set up on HDFS.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how it fails?  You should be able to authenticate with HDFS the same way you authenticate with YARN.  There may be some additional configuration of the HDFS security settings that you need.

Comment: I made another question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35986055/1395437

Comment: Ah I see.  That doesn't really help much does it...